# Response empty even when responseservlet filled

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I deploy the same war with jetty, a local tomcat and a remote tomcat.
For the same request :

- With jetty and local tomcat everything is fine and I get a full response.
- With remote tomcat response status is 200 but with empty body.

I don't know where to look at and why this difference.
If you can provide me another way to query an URL (which can be public or local to the network where the app is deployed), I'll be glad to hear it.
The code

```
private void get(String proxiedURIString, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = getHttpURLConnection(proxiedURIString, resp);
    fillHeaders(resp, connection);
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), resp.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String message = String.format("Unable to parse response : %s", proxiedURIString);
        LOGGER.error(message);
        resp.sendError(500, message);
    } finally {
        resp.getOutputStream().flush();
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    LOGGER.info("Successfully proxied URI : {}", proxiedURIString);
}

private static void fillHeaders(HttpServletResponse resp, HttpURLConnection connection) {
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = connection.getHeaderFields();
    for (String header : headers.keySet()) {
        if(header == null || headers.get(header) == null) {
            continue;
        }
        for (String headerValue : headers.get(header)) {
            if(headerValue == null) {
                continue;
            }
            resp.addHeader(header, headerValue);
        }
    }
}

private static HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(String proxiedURIString, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(proxiedURIString);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String message = String.format("Unable to contact : %s", proxiedURIString);
        LOGGER.error(message);
        resp.sendError(404, message);
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Edit: Edit the code to only work with input/output streams. Also to provide further information, I contact the remote tomcat through an apache http server and the response body is big.
Edit2: Futher information. I mapped the proxied URI with one sending much less data and this time I get a full answer for every configuration.

Comment: It may not at all be the issue, but you should not use `Reader`s/`Writer`s to copy the contents of your remote connection. Stick to `InputStream`/`OutputStream`, or you expose yourself to various encoding issues and errors. If you have to use `Reader`, use the Content-Type header to know your connection's response charset and instantiate your `InputStreamReader` accordingly. But nothing really mandates that HTTP content be interpreted as Strings, so using `Reader`s definitely look like a bad design decision.

Comment: You may be encoutering HTTP level issues. Could you please add an example of ContentType + Transfer-Encoding + Content-Encoding headers when your app succeeds, vs. fails ?

In particular, your design looks prone to fail when the HTTP content being proxies uses chunked transfer encoding (which is more frequent with larger response bodies).

Can you try replace your HTTPUrlConnection with an HTTP Client connection (such as Commons HTTP from Apache) ? The idea would be to let the HTTP encoding-aware library strip the InputStream of HTTP specifities, giving you the raw data.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide more information at the moment about the failing request as the server is down and I don't manage it. I have to wait until it is restarted. But I am changing my code to use Apache's HttpClientConnection. I will add a comment about good vs bad responses' headers as soon as possible. Thx for your help guys.

Comment: I just checked a bit of documentation and I may be mistaken in my prior comment : HTTPUrlConnection should automatically strip HTTP specific transfer encoding, juste as Apache HTTPClient does.

But anyway, more logs (of headers and maybe of the content being copied) should help narrowing things down

Comment: I finally use jetty ProxyServlet which works fine for me because I can't spend more time investigating. I would like to but I can't connect to the remote server, ssh is disabled by the provider, and I have to move on to other tasks. Thx for your help.